# Simple Discrete Random Variable Problem

Tags: combinatorics, random-variables

A shipment of 12 similar computers arrive at a retail outlet with 3 defective
items. The computers are randomly selected and tested until all 3 defective
items are identified. Let X be the number of computers that are tested.

Find P(X = 7)
I mean I know it is very easy so what I did was
X is 7 then the seventh is defective.
So the numerator should be (9 choose 4)*(3 choose 2)
Denominator should be (12 choose 7)
It may be right , that was my compulsive answer , but I always have this feeling that i should multiply somewhere by 3! But then I read similar and I say the answer is enough .

Thoughts anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that exactly $2$ of the first $6$ are bad, and therefore $4$ are good is
$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{12}{6}}.$$
*Given this has happened,* the probability the $7$-th is bad is $\dfrac{1}{6}$. It follows that our required probability is
$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{12}{6}}\cdot \frac{1}{6}.$$

*Remark:* You calculated the probability that the $3$ bad are among the first $7$ choices. This includes, for example, the $3$ bad being found in $3$ choices, or $4$, and so on up to $7$.

One could use your kind of reasoning to give an alternate calculation.  You found $\Pr(X\le 7)$. The required probability is $\Pr(X=7)$, which is $\Pr(X\le 7)-\Pr(X\le 6)$. You could find $\Pr(X\le 6)$ using the same idea as the one you used for $\Pr(X\le 7)$, and then subtract.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you , now its clear , I just need more practice with random variables and the different types of examples , in my university no recitation is given for this course , the professor tries to include some examples in class but I guess it is not enough for a course like this

Comment: You are welcome.